# If two group actions on a set are both transitive, must they be the same?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Suppose we have a group $G$ and a set $S$ and two different group actions
$$
 \phi:G \to \mathrm{Sym}(S) \qquad \psi:G \to \mathrm{Sym}(S)
$$
so that both $\phi$ and $\psi$ are transitive. Can we conclude from this that $\phi = \psi$? If not, what is a counterexample? If not, are there situations in which this does hold, for example, if $S$ is finite?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$G$ acts on itself by left multiplication, $g(x) = gx$, and by right multiplication, $g(x)=xg^{-1}$.

These actions are both transitive, but are not the same except in very special cases -- e.g. by setting $x=1$ we see that it is a necessary condition (which turns out to be sufficient) that every element has order at most $2$.

Every such group is abelian and a vector space over $\mathbb F_2$, and if its dimension is $\ge 2$, Robert Chamberlain's answer gives another set of different group actions.

The only groups where your property can be true are therefore the trivial group and $C_2$ -- and in both these cases it *is* actually true, though not very interestingly so.

(It is also trivially true if $|S|\le 1$, which is even less interesting -- and *vacuously* true if there are no transitive actions at all, such as if $|S|$ is nonzero and fails to divide $|G|$).

Comment: But these two action are equivalent under the mapping $x \mapsto x^{-1}$, so it depends on what you mean by "the same". Just as when people talk about two groups being the same they often really mean isomorphic, my instinctive interpretation of two actions being the same is that they are equivalent. In Robert Chamberlain's example, the two actions are inequivalent.

Comment: @Derek: The question asked whether $\phi=\psi$ with an actual equals sign; I think that asks for more than just an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 7):

We cannot, for example if $G=C_2\times C_2$ is generated by $x,y$ where $C_2$ is the cyclic group of order $2$ then $G$ acts transitively on the set $\{1,2\}$ in multiple ways - we can have $\phi:x\mapsto (1,2), y\mapsto (1,2)$ and $\psi:x\mapsto (1,2), y\mapsto\mathrm{id}$

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb{Z}/3$ acts on $\{1,2,3\}$ by the actions defined on its generators $1$, $f_1(1)=2,f_1(2)=3, f_1(3)=1$ and $g_1(1)=3, g_1(2)=1, g_1(3)=2$  and these actions are different.

Comment: Yes but they are equivalent. As I said in my comment about Henning Makholm's example, people who work in the area of group actions would typically  mean "equivalent" when they say "the same".